# Finding duplicate data in two different columns in two different excel files vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, loops

my code highlights duplicate values within the two columns in two different based on the rows. its somehow unable to find duplicate vales if the column order is changed. suggestions?

```
Public Sub CompareColumns(sourceCol As String, targetCol As String, sourceExcelFile As String, targetExcelFile As String)

        Try
            excelApp = New Excel.Application()
            excelApp.Visible = False
         excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(sourceExcelFile)
            excelWorkbook2 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(targetExcelFile)
            excelWorkSheet1 = excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            excelWorkSheet2 = excelWorkbook2.ActiveSheet

            lastLineSource = excelWorkSheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            LastLineTarget = excelWorkSheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            For row As Integer = 1 To lastLineSource
                If excelWorkSheet1.Range(sourceCol & row.ToString()).Value = excelWorkSheet2.Range(targetCol & row.ToString()).Value Then
                     excelWorkSheet2.Range(targetCol & row.ToString()).Interior.Color = 5296274


                End If
            Next

            excelWorkbook.Save()
            excelWorkbook2.Save()
            excelWorkbook.Close()
            excelWorkbook2.Close()


            excelApp.Quit()
        Catch
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub
```

the expected output is for all the duplicate values in the target workbook found in the source workbook to be to be highlighted regardless of column order(sort)

Answer (score 0):

So I think that You should use dictionary:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet

You can loop through all values in the first workbook and add it to dictionary.
Then You should loop through all cells in the second workbook and if You find value in dictionary, then You have duplicate, if not then there is not the duplicate.

It works regardless the order (sort) and is quite fast.